# What does Islam say about oral sex outside marriage while being married

Tags: nikah, sex

What does Islam say about someone who identified themselves as gay after marriage and has oral sex with other men secretly while being married to a woman.

Comment: Please perform basic research on your own and ask useful questions. The Islamic stance on homosexual relations and relations outside of marriage is well known and easily be found.

Answer (score -1):

It is Haram in Islam for males to keep sexual or wrong relations with males, and same goes for females they are also sinful if they keep wrong or sexual relationships with females. In Islam keeping sexual relationship with your wife is halal only.